# How to break a for loop in one function based off of another function

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach, console-application

I have a method called `RunGame` that contains an array of tiles. I then have a `foreach` loop that calls another method called `CheckValid` that passes in the tile number and a game number. When the checkvalid is called, it checks a field in the database to see if it is null or not. What I would like to do is make the foreach statement stop running if it finds a field that is not null. This is what I currently have:

```
public void RunGame()
{
    try
    {
        int[,] game = new int[10, 1] { { 70 }, { 71 }, { 62 }, { 14 }, { 71 }, { 12 }, { 12 }, { 41 }, { 19 }, { 71 } };
        int num = 2;

        foreach (int i in game)
        {
            CheckValid(i, num);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public void CheckValid(int tile, int game)
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CheckValid", Conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tileVal", tile);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("num", game);
        Conn.Open();
        
        using (MySqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                if (read[0] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"This tile is occupied");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Tile {tile} is not occupied");
                }
            }
            read.Close();
        }
        Conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I would like it to run based on the conditions of this if statement:

```
if (read[0] != DBNull.Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"This tile is occupied");
    //Stop the foreach loop
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Tile {tile} is not occupied");
    //Continue the foreach loop
}
```

Currently, it prints this when tile 71 is occupied:

```
Tile 70 is not occupied
This tile is occupied //I would like it to stop before it prints this line
Tile 62 is not occupied
Tile 14 is not occupied
This tile is occupied
Tile 12 is not occupied
Tile 12 is not occupied
Tile 41 is not occupied
Tile 19 is not occupied
This tile is occupied
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Use a "break" to exit the for loop.

Comment: Note that it is unnecessary to call `Close` on the reader as the `using` statement will handle that as part of `Dispose`. Also it appears you are storing and sharing a `MySqlConnection` object (`Conn`)--**don't do that!** Create it as close to the code where you need it as possible and destroy (`Dispose`) when you are done. Let connection pooling work for you. Then you also have no need to manually `Close` the connection either.

Comment: Thanks @pinkfloydx33 for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a method like this to return a `bool` (true/false) value:

```
public bool CheckValid(int tile, int game)
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CheckValid", Conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tileVal", tile);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("num", game);
        Conn.Open();
        using (MySqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                if (read[0] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"This tile is occupied");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Tile {tile} is not occupied");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            read.Close();
        }
        Conn.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then change your other code like this to check the result of `CheckValid`:

```
if (!CheckValid(i, num))
{
    break;
}
```

You can thus use the boolean result to determine whether you should continue executing your loop or not.

Note that I've modified `CheckValid` in such a way that it will return `false` is there is no data (meaning the loop will `break;`). If you wawnt the opposite, change `return false;` to `return true;`

Comment: By the way, I would be tempted to rename `CheckValid` to `IsTileValid` (or perhaps better still: `IsTileVacant`) as I feel that's closer to the intention of the method now: it returns information about validity rather than simply checking for itself.

Comment: It is worth to note that a function named `CheckValid` (or `IsValid`) **is expected** to return a boolean value (in general) stating if the passed parameters are indeed valid or not

Comment: @Rafalon Good point. I've revised my suggestion to `IsTileValid` / `IsTileVacant` :)